# Joining potentially blank fields in a Power Automate expression without `compact`?

Tags: power-automate

A pretty typical operation is to combine first, middle, and last names into a display name often with last naming coming first, a comma and then the rest such as "Doe, John".

I mean look at this abomination.  It works, but it only joins first and last.  If middle was present it would be even uglier.

```js
join(
  if(empty(outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_lastname']),
    if(empty(outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_firstname']), 
      createArray(), 
      createArray(outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_firstname'])),
    if(empty(outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_firstname']), 
      createArray(outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_lastname']),
      createArray(outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_lastname'], outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID')?['body/new_firstname']))),
  ', ')
```

I mean `join` is, I think, what you want, but the repetition is, unfortunately, necessary.

Is there another form one could use to avoid all the repetition?  If a `compact` function were available it would eliminate the redundancy completely, and `coalesce` is useful outside an array, but not helpful here.

Obviously, this attempts to handle nulls in any field so we get "Doe" or "John" without a comma.

Comment: Maybe look at using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.  It's not overly expensive and has a great set of data transformation operations available.  Could make your life a bit easier.

Comment: Will look.  If I discover a good option, I'll return and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: You can use Azure Functions to do that but they're much more integrated in LogicApps, less so in PowerAutomate, or you can use the in-line Javascript action, again though, only in LogicApps.  They're looking at adding more languages to that as well.  Maybe you should look at changing over to LogicApps.  PowerAutomate sits on the LogicApps engine.  The Advanced Data Operations connector has a whole heap of built in custom functions that further extend on the ones offered in PA/LA, it's quite powerful ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/custom-functions/

Comment: I've already used Azure Functions to that end (for Regex stuff!) but it's expensive having to initiate a network call for some trivial operation.  I just was hoping Power Automate might see the need for adopting a few more functions that help with these kinds of situations.

Comment: My company built a connector that is attempting to do exactly what you’re asking (in the general sense that is) but we’re also in the process of developing a C# script function that will help folks like yourself to. It have to spin up an Azure function just to solve something like this. Check it out, it has regex built in as well as more operations being certified as we speak … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/